# Remix submit form onChange and get live update from useActionData()

Tags: reactjs, forms, action, onchange, remix

I am trying to create a remix page where i want to get live preview when i change a `Select` tag. It is going through a Form since i want it to translate the data.

A solution to my problem could be to make `preventDefault`(first code example) to work or to find a way to make `useActionData()`(second code example) to work when using `useFetcher`

With this code, the `preventDefault` does not work. I need `preventDefault` to work so that the selector doesn't reset. I could make the action function also send the name so that the DefaultValue in select is imported from action function, but this is going to become a big form and i dont want to refresh the whole page.

```
export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
    const form = new URLSearchParams(await request.text())
    const name = form.get('name');
    console.log('name', name);
    return json({ message: name ? `Hello ${name}!` : 'Select name' });
}

export default function Page() {
    const actionData = useActionData();
    console.log('actionData', actionData);

    return (
        <>
            <Form method="post">

                <h1>{actionData ? actionData.message : 'Select name.'}</h1>

                <select 
                    name="name" 
                    onChange={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.target.form.submit();
                    }}
                >
                    <option value="name 1">Name 1</option>
                    <option value="name 2">Name 2</option>
                    <option value="name 3">Name 3</option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">
                    Submit
                </button>

                </Form>
        </>
    );
}
```

I have also tried following https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/1807 using `useRef and useFetcher`, but even tho the action function runs, it gives me `undefined`  when logging actionData.

```
export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
    const form = new URLSearchParams(await request.text())
    const name = form.get('name');
    console.log('name', name);
    return json({ message: name ? `Hello ${name}!` : 'Select name' });
}

export default function Page() {
    const actionData = useActionData();
    console.log('actionData', actionData); // Gives undefined

    const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
    const fetcher = useFetcher();

    return (
        <>
            <fetcher.Form method="post" ref={formRef}>

                <h1>{actionData ? actionData.message : 'Select name.'}</h1>

                <select 
                    name="name" 
                    onChange={() => {
                        fetcher.submit(formRef.current);
                    }}
                >
                    <option value="name 1">Name 1</option>
                    <option value="name 2">Name 2</option>
                    <option value="name 3">Name 3</option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">
                    Submit
                </button>

            </fetcher.Form >
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it was to use fetcher.load, and then have it as a own loader file.

Main file test.tsx:

```
import { useFetcher } from '@remix-run/react';

export default function Page() {
    const fetcher = useFetcher();
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>{fetcher.data ? fetcher.data.message : 'Select name.'}</h1>

                <select
                    name="name"
                    onChange={e => {
                        fetcher.load(`loader/?name=${e.target.value}`);
                    }} 
                >
                    <option value="name 1">Name 1</option>
                    <option value="name 2">Name 2</option>
                    <option value="name 3">Name 3</option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Loaderfile loader.ts:

```
import type { LoaderArgs } from '@remix-run/node';
import { json } from '@remix-run/node';

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderArgs) {
    const form = new URLSearchParams(await request.text());
    const name = form.get('name');
    return json({ message: name ? `Hello ${name}!` : 'Select name' });
}
```